# Execution of fork processes

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, wait

Who will execute the printf line (the initial process after all processes finished or every process)?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
    {
        fork();
    }
    while(wait(NULL)>0);
    printf("finished\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All. It is straightforward from the code. No `exit()` is called in any created child and they are free to execute what parent executes. So each child executes `printf()` once. This can be programmatically verified as below:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main()
{

        printf("PID = %d\n", getpid());
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 
         {
                if (fork() == 0)
                        printf("PID = %d\n", getpid());
         }
        while(wait(NULL)>0);
        printf("PID: %d finished\n", getpid());
}
```

OUTPUT

```
$ ./a.out 
PID = 120360
PID = 120361
PID = 120362
PID = 120364
PID = 120363
PID = 120366
PID: 120363 finished
PID: 120366 finished
PID = 120367
PID = 120365
PID: 120367 finished
PID: 120365 finished
PID: 120362 finished
PID: 120364 finished
PID: 120361 finished
PID: 120360 finished
```

From the above output, it can be seen that each created child is executing `printf()` once.